# Finding text child of an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to find the text snippet "This is for testing selector" from the following DOM structure using plain JavaScript.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            <a title=" Home" href="http://www.google.com/"> Home</a> 
            <span class="arrow">»</span>
            <a title="abc" href="http://www.google.com/">test1</a> 
            <span class="arrow">»</span><a title="xyz" href="http://www.google.com/">test2</a> 
            <span class="arrow">»</span> 
            This is for testing selector
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSoup is your friend

Comment: nopes... only javascript

Comment: can you please clarify what your question is

Comment: what is it you're actually asking?!

Comment: using java script selector want to select the text which i mentioned

Comment: when you say "select" what do you mean? change its color? or highlight it as if you were selecting it with a mouse? your question is very unclear.

Comment: just try to select that text by any selector for ex id, class, tagname what so ever and do console.log("text");

Comment: Will that chuck of text always be in the [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) position in relation to `div.breadcrumb`? Hence `document.querySelector('div.breadcrumb').lastChild.textContent`

Comment: not working @ bloody, Can you check the same in your console panel

Comment: There it is: http://jsbin.com/zizawo/edit?html,js,console Is that not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumb')[0].lastChild;
```

Note that this would only work if the text "This is for testing selector" remains as the last child in the `breadcrumb`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the code in this answer: [Select text in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript)

If, however, you're not trying to make the container contenteditable and want only to make the text appear highlighted, you could do something like this:

```
var textToHighlight = "This is for testing selector";
var breadcrumb = document.querySelector("#breadcrumb");
breadcrumb.innerHTML.replace(textToHighlight,
           "<span style='background-color:red'>" + textToHighlight + "</span>");
```

Comment: nixkuroi i dont want to hard code the value of variable textToHighlight, can you inspect and get by any selector help like tagname or classname what so ever...

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a simpler solutions, but this also works:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb")[0];
var children = element.childNodes;
for (i in children) {
  if (children[i] instanceof Text) {
    content = children[i].textContent;
    if (content.trim() != "") {
      alert(content);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <a title=" Home" href="http://www.google.com/"> Home</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span>
    <a title="abc" href="http://www.google.com/">test1</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span><a title="xyz" href="http://www.google.com/">test2</a> 
    <span class="arrow">»</span> This is for testing selector
  </div>
</body>
```

This code iterates through the children of the div, and searches for text nodes. It will alert the one not empty.

(only tested with chrome)

Answer (score 0):

If the text you want to select is always after all the tags in wrapped in the `div.breadcrumb` tag, as in your example, then use this:

`document.querySelector('div.breadcrumb').lastChild.textContent.trim()`

Use the `querySelector` method to access the `div.breadcrumb` element, then access the `lastChild` property on that element, which gives you the textNode you're looking for. Now just get the text on that element using the `textContent` property, and finally use the `trim` method to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces and line returns.

[JSBin example.](http://jsbin.com/zizawo/edit?html,js,console)